# Extracting abstract nouns and adjectives from a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis, pos-tagger

I am working on a data frame that has one of the columns containing feedback text. It has been cleaned.
All I need to know is how to extract the abstract nouns and adjectives from the string.

Here's a sample of the cleaned text that I have:

[image]

The output must contain only the abstract nouns and the adjectives from each feedback.

For instance, the feedback is:

```
"smells good also nice taste in love with it"
```

The output should be:

```
good nice love
```

I tried using nltk pos tagger and the textblob lexicon. I could extract all the adjectives using textblob but in the case of nouns, it is tagging all the nouns. I am not able to separate out just the abstract nouns, like 'love' in the example mentioned.

Comment: what did you try to do so far

Comment: I tried using nltk pos tagger and the textblob lexicon. I could extract all the adjectives using textblob but in the case of nouns, it is tagging all the nouns. I am not able to separate out just the abstract nouns, like 'love' in the example mentioned. @ArkodeepRay

Comment: "taste" is a noun. Why don't you want it?

Comment: I would love to have it. My mistake for not adding in the output, apologies. 
But the point I am trying to make is I need to extract just the abstract nouns ( not the proper, common, collective or any other forms).

Comment: Suppose the sentence was 'I love staying in Texas'. The only extracted words I would need is 'love' and not 'Texas', that is, just the abstract nouns.
Hope I am able to convey my point.

Comment: I am afraid you do not know what "abstract noun" means. "Love" is an abstract noun, but "room" is not. If you want to remove proper nouns, you should use named entity recognition (NER), but it is quite unreliable. Sometimes it is hard to tell a _proper_ noun from a _common_ noun.

Comment: @Noni in "I love staying in Texas", _love_ is a verb, not a noun. There are no 'abstract' nouns in that sentence.

Comment: @DavidDale Yes, that worked for me. I tried that. Thank you.

Comment: @OliverMason yes, my bad. It would be an abstract noun if I use it in a sentence like, maybe, "Send them my love".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatically incorrect (it misses the first subject "it"). NLP tools are usually not comfortable with parsing incorrect sentences. However, NLTK parses even the original sentence almost correctly:

```
s = "smells good also nice taste in love with it"
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(s))
#[('smells', 'NNS'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('also', 'RB'), ('nice', 'JJ'), 
# ('taste', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('love', 'NN'), ('with', 'IN'), ('it', 'PRP')]
```

If you correct the grammar, the results are 100% correct:

```
s = "it smells good also nice taste in love with it"
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(s))
#[('it', 'PRP'), ('smells', 'VBZ'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('also', 'RB'), 
# ('nice', 'JJ'), ('taste', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('love', 'NN'), 
# ('with', 'IN'), ('it', 'PRP')]
```

And the output that you want:

```
[word for word,tag in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(s)) if tag[0] in "NJ"]
#['good', 'nice', 'taste', 'love']
```

Comment: With feedback or other user input text you can never be sure it's grammatical. And most NLP tools can actually cope with that, otherwise they'd be pretty useless.